# TypeError: expect.any is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Im using create-react-app and Im trying to write a test in jest for my action creator. One of the fields that the action adds is a random ID so I want to use expect.any(String) so that the test will pass. However I'm getting `TypeError: expect.any is not a function`

Here is my test:

```
describe('actions', () => {

it('should create an action to add a ticket', () => {
 const payload = {
     summary: 'A summary',
     description: 'A description',
     status:'open',
     priority: 'minor',
  };

  const expected = {
    type: actions.ADD_TICKET,
    ticket: {
          ...payload,
          id: expect.any(String),
      },
  };

  const actual = addTicket(payload);

  expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
 })
})
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on 18.1.0

Comment: Well at least I'm not crazy.

Comment: Filed an issue https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

expect.any was added in Jest 18 which wasnt shipping with this version of create-react-app. The version they just pushed now supports it